# How to include check all box in html sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-apps-script

I have the following code for generating checkboxes in a Google Docs sidebar:

```
for( var i = 0;i < values.length; i ++)
        {
        var cb = document.createElement( "input" );
        cb.type = "checkbox";
        cb.id = values[i][1];
        cb.value = values[i][0];
        var text = document.createTextNode( values[i][0].substring(0, 30) );
        var br = document.createElement('br');
        document.getElementById( 'class_list' ).appendChild( cb );
        document.getElementById( 'class_list' ).appendChild( text );
        document.getElementById( 'class_list' ).appendChild( br );     
       }
```

Is there a way to include a **check all** box at the top of this list and then pass all of the selected values and ids to another function?

Comment: Looks like you are building the HTML in client side code.  My experience has been that it's faster to build the HTML on the server.  But it's a personal preference.  I use an HTML file that is a template, and then use HTML Service to evaluate the template.  I find it easier to layout the HTML in a file.  I added the DOM tag if you want to stay with your current way.  Currently, this really isn't an Apps Script question.

Comment: @SandyGood I can try server side. Any hints to create select all checkbox and pass the selected to another function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the HTML and client side JavaScript that will do what you want:

```
<div class="inputFormElement"><!-- Beginning of input -->

  <button onmouseup="checkAllBoxes()">Select All</button>

  <br>
  <br>

  <div class="chkBoxListElement">
    <input type="checkbox" id="idOne" value="1">One<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idTwo" value="2">Two<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idThree" value="3">Three<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idFour" value="4">Four<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idFive" value="5">Five<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idSix" value="6">Six<br>
  </div>

</div><!-- End of input -->

<script>
window.checkAllBoxes = function() {
  var allCheckBoxes,dataAsString,elementHoldingChkBoxes,i,L,objectOfData,thisChkBox,thisID;

  objectOfData = {};

  elementHoldingChkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('chkBoxListElement')[0];
  console.log('elementHoldingChkBoxes: ' + elementHoldingChkBoxes)
  console.log('typeof elementHoldingChkBoxes: ' + typeof elementHoldingChkBoxes)

  allCheckBoxes = elementHoldingChkBoxes.getElementsByTagName('input');//Get all inputs

  L = allCheckBoxes.length;

  for (i=0;i<L;i++) {
    thisChkBox = allCheckBoxes[i];//Get this check box
    if (thisChkBox) {//Not null, undefined or empty string - truthy
      thisChkBox.checked = true;
      thisID = thisChkBox.id;
      objectOfData[thisID] = thisChkBox.value;
    }
  }

  dataAsString = JSON.stringify(objectOfData);//Convert object to a string
  console.log('dataAsString: ' + dataAsString)

  mySecondFunction(objectOfData);
}

window.mySecondFunction = function(data) {
  console.log(data)

}
</script>
```

If you want the input boxes to dynamically change whenever the sidebar is loaded, some code will be needed to build the HTML.  But that is another question.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to use your code as a guide to create select all, clear all, and to dynamically build checkboxes, works great.